# Python data to dict memory concerns: how to efficiently load data into a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to load a very large dataset (~560MB) into a dict in order to display it as a 3D graph.
I have run into memory issues that resulted in "Killed.", so I've added some logic to read my dataset in chunks and dump the dict to a json file periodically, I hoped this would avoid my RAM being filled up.
However, I still get it killed after reaching about 4.00M/558.0M progress.

I want to understand how this roughly 560MB file is costing me gigabytes of RAM just to cut away unwanted columns and transform into a dict? And if there's any more efficient methods to get to what I need: a data object where I can efficiently extract sets of coords with their vals.

Please find my code and some example data below:

```
import json
import logging
import os

import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def create_grid_dict(file_path, chunk_size=500000):
    """
    :param file_path: Path to a grid file.
    :param chunk_size: Number of lines to process before dumping into json
    :return: Dictionary object containing the gist grid data with as index the voxel number
             and as values the x, y and z coordinates, and the value
    """
    # Read the data from the file
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        # Read the first line
        header = file.readline().strip()
        header2 = file.readline().strip()
        # Log the header
        logging.info(header)
    columns = header2.split(' ')

    # Get the file size
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

    output_file = 'datasets/cache.json'
    # Check if the output file already exists
    if os.path.exists(output_file):
        with open(output_file, 'r') as f:
            grid_dict = json.load(f)
            return grid_dict
    else:
        # Create an empty dictionary to store the grid data
        grid_dict = {}

    logging.info(f"Reading file size {file_size} in chunks of {chunk_size} lines.")
    # Read the file in chunks
    with tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc="Processing") as pbar:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=2, names=columns, chunksize=chunk_size):
            # Filter out the columns you need
            chunk = chunk[['voxel', 'xcoord', 'ycoord', 'zcoord', 'val1', 'val2']]

            # Iterate through each row in the chunk
            for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
                voxel = row['voxel']
                # Store the values in the dictionary
                grid_dict[voxel] = {
                    'xcoord': row['xcoord'],
                    'ycoord': row['ycoord'],
                    'zcoord': row['zcoord'],
                    'val': row['val1'] + 2 * row['val2']
                }
            pbar.update(chunk_size)

            # Write the grid dictionary to the output file after processing each chunk
            with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(grid_dict, f)
    return grid_dict
```

```
# Example space-delimited dataset
voxel xcoord ycoord zcoord val1 val2
1 0.1 0.2 0.3 10 5
2 0.2 0.3 0.4 8 4
3 0.3 0.4 0.5 12 6
4 0.4 0.5 0.6 15 7
5 0.5 0.6 0.7 9 3
6 0.6 0.7 0.8 11 5
7 0.7 0.8 0.9 13 6
8 0.8 0.9 1.0 14 7
9 0.9 1.0 1.1 16 8
10 1.0 1.1 1.2 18 9
```

Comment: How would reading chunked or saving to a file help when you keep adding the data to the same `grid_dict` anyway? By the end of the chunks it will contain all the data in the csv plus overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not just making a `dict`, you're making a `dict` of `dict`s, each of which incurs a non-trivial amount of overhead (on my machine, each of your small `dict`s adds 184 bytes of overhead all by itself). Your chunking is nigh unto useless, because the `dict` of `dict`s keeps growing, the (likely fairly efficiently stored) dataframe is likely not all that important, memory-wise.

One thing you could try to do to reduce that overhead is to have your `dict` map to slotted classesinstead of `dict`s, and use `dataclasses.asdict` to make them encode to the `dict` form:

```
import dataclasses
import json

@dataclasses.dataclass(slots=True)  # slots=True optimizes to store only the declared attributes with less memory
class Voxel:
    xcoord: float
    ycoord: float
    zcoord: float
    val: int
```

then change the relevant part of your loop to:

```
            for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
                voxel = row['voxel']
                # Store the values in the dict
                grid_dict[voxel] = Voxel(row['xcoord'],
                                         row['ycoord'],
                                         row['zcoord'],
                                         row['val1'] + 2 * row['val2']
                                        )
            pbar.update(chunk_size)

            # Write the grid dictionary to the output file after processing each chunk
            with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(grid_dict, f, default=dataclasses.asdict)  # Converts to dict lazily just in time to convert it to a string, rather than all at once
```

`dataclasses` both make the custom class quicker to declare, and provide the `dataclasses.asdict` helper to make serializing them easy (`collections.namedtuple`/`typing.NamedTuple` might seem like they work, but unfortunately, they're interpreted as plain `tuple`s and serialized as JSON Arrays).

The net savings here, on my local Python install, is 120 bytes per `Voxel` (the `dict` overhead is 184 bytes per-`dict`, vs. 64 bytes per-`Voxel` instance). If you're close to being able to fit in memory, this might be enough to get you there.